# How do I refactor android code to choose layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, refactoring, android-linearlayout

I have 1 top layout and 3 bottom layouts, a user drags items from top layout to one of the 3 below.

[image: dd]

The code below:

- puts sequentially every image in every bottom layout into a list
- removes items from each bottom layout
- puts them back into top layout

  ```
      public void onClick(View view) {
      LinearLayout bottomLinearLayout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom1);
      LinearLayout bottomLinearLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom2);
      LinearLayout bottomLinearLayout3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom3);
      LinearLayout topLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.topLinear);

      int total_num1 = bottomLinearLayout1.getChildCount();
      int total_num2 = bottomLinearLayout2.getChildCount();
      int total_num3 = bottomLinearLayout3.getChildCount();

      View current_image = null;
      List<View> listOfkids = new ArrayList<>() ;

      //************ REPEATS **************

      for(int i = 0 ; i < total_num1 ; i++){
          current_image = bottomLinearLayout1.getChildAt(i);
          listOfkids.add(current_image);
      }
      bottomLinearLayout1.removeAllViews();

      for(int i = 0 ; i < listOfkids.size();i++){
          topLinearLayout.addView( listOfkids.get(i));
      }
      listOfkids.clear();

      //************ REPEATS **************

      for(int i = 0 ; i < total_num2 ; i++){
          current_image = bottomLinearLayout2.getChildAt(i);
          listOfkids.add(current_image);
      }
      bottomLinearLayout2.removeAllViews();
      for(int i = 0 ; i < listOfkids.size();i++){
          topLinearLayout.addView( listOfkids.get(i));
      }
      listOfkids.clear();

      //************ REPEATS **************

      for(int i = 0 ; i < total_num3 ; i++){
          current_image = bottomLinearLayout3.getChildAt(i);
          listOfkids.add(current_image);
      }
      bottomLinearLayout3.removeAllViews();
      for(int i = 0 ; i < listOfkids.size();i++){
          topLinearLayout.addView( listOfkids.get(i));
      }
  ```

Basically, the only difference between these loops is the last digit in "bottomLinearLayout"; the other code just copies itself!

Can i do this:

```
if(id == R.id.bottom1){
String current_layout = "bottomLinearLayout" + 1 ;
}
else if( id == R.id.bottom2){
 current_layout = "bottomLinearLayout" + 2 ;
}
else if( id == R.id.bottom3){
 current_layout = "bottomLinearLayout" + 3 ;
}
```

and then add this string as **a command right into the java source code**?

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to refactor the `onClick` method, you could create an array of the layout ids and iterate through them as follows:

```
int bottomLayoutIds[]        = {R.id.bottom1, R.id.bottom2, R.id.bottom3};
LinearLayout topLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.topLinear);

for (int layoutId : bottomLayoutIds){
    LinearLayout bottomLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(layoutId);
    int childCount = bottomLinearLayout.getChildCount();
    List<View> listOfKids = new ArrayList<>() ;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < childCount ; i++){
        View currentImage = bottomLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        listOfKids.add(currentImage);
    }
    bottomLinearLayout.removeAllViews();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < listOfKids.size();i++){
        topLinearLayout.addView( listOfKids.get(i));
    }
}
```